# Filter Index-2 to Index+2 in Datatables

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I'm currently displaying a table returning player rankings and highlighting the current player row. What I would like to achieve is let's say display on 5 rows and center the current player at the center.

If the current player ranking is 100th, I want to display player ranks 98 to 102. Currently it will display rank 1 to 5.

I can't find a want to "center my results" on the current player ranking.

My current table is displayed with this code:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "myController/getDataTable",
    method: 'post',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (values) {
        var table = $('#myTableLeaderboard').DataTable({
            paging: true,
            pageLength: 5,
            sort: true,
            searching: true,
            data: values['data'],
            ordering: true,
            aoColumns: [
                { "data": "ranking" },
                { "data": "cash" },
                { "data": "staff_count" }
                // more columns...
            ],
            "createdRow": function ( row, data, index ) {
                $currentUserId = $('#currentUserId').attr('value');
                if ( data.id_player == $currentUserId ) {
                    $('td', row).addClass('bold');
                }
            }
        });
        $('#myTableLeaderboard_filter').switchClass( 'dataTables_filter', 'dataTables_filter_show' ); 
    }
});
```

My server side PHP function returns two arrays, one containing the data for the table and one variable containing the current player rank:

```
{"data":
    [{"cash":"606, "id_player":"61","staff_count":null,"ranking":1},
    {"cash":"30","id_player":"63","staff_count":null,"ranking":2},
    ...more players....],
"current_id_player":"67",
"current_player_ranking":3
}
```

I looked into the [Custom filtering - range search](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html) page but I'm not sure that's what I should look into and how to approach it.

Finally, paging is enabled so if the player navigates to another page, the results won't be "centered" on him anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution with adding:

```
displayStart: values.current_player_ranking-2,
```

And completed with [jumpToData](https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/page.jumpToData()) plugin

```
$('#myTableLeaderboard thead').on('click', 'th', function () {   
    table.page.jumpToData( $currentUserId, 9 );
} );
table.page.jumpToData( $currentUserId, 9 );
```